# Genric XSLT style sheet to transform xml

Tags: xslt

I am looking for some help building an XSLT stylesheet. I have provided the input XML. I need it transformed to the output XML shown.

I am thinking ..

1. start from the root node
2. traverse the tree to check if attribute or element.
3. If element , then string concat and format in

   ```
   <businessElements>
                 <key>requestId</key>
                 <type>String</type>
                 <value>TV00001001</value>
    </businessElements>
   ```

### Input XML

```
<entity1>
    <requestID>TV00001001</requestID> //nested entities 
    <entity2>
      <effectiveDt>2001-12-31T12:00:00</effectiveDt> // attribute with value 
      <companyCd>companyCd</companyCd>
      < entity3>
        <vo1>
          <att1>true</ att1>
          < att2>vehicleId</att2>
          <att3>true</att3>

       </vo1>
      </ entity3>
</ entity2>
</ entity1>
```

### Output XML

```
< entity1>
    <businessElements>
                  <key>requestId</key>
                  <type>String</type>
                  <value>TV00001001</value>
     </businessElements>
    < entity2>
        <businessElements>
                     <key>effectiveDt</key>
                     <type>Date</type>
                 <value>12/11/2016</value>
         </businessElements>
       <businessElements>
                     <key>companyCd</key>
                     <type>String</type>
                     <value>0001</value>
         </businessElements>
      < entity3>
        < vo1>
               <businessElements>
                           <key>vehicleId</key>
                           <type>String</type>
                           <value>5</value>
            </businessElements>

        </ vo1>
      </ entity3>
</ entity2>
</ entity1>
```

Comment: This is my first attempt

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">

 <!-- Select every element and attribute -->
 <xsl:for-each select="//*|//*/@*">
   
  <!-- Check if node is an attribute or an element -->
   <xsl:template match="@*">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat ('<businessElements>',@symbol,' - ', name)" />

Comment: I see no attempt.  Write a style sheet, post the output, and ask specific questions.  We aren't an XSLT stylesheet service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer archive for programming problems, not a code-writing service for lazy people.

Comment: **1.** Neither your input not the output are well-formed XML documents. -- **2.** In XML, the word *attribute* has a very precise meaning; there are no attributes in your input.

Comment: Yes Sir , Your answer satisfies my initial requirement. For the Type right now I have hardcoded the value as string . But I would like to read the XSD in this style sheet and based on the name match , I would like to get the type for the element .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no discernible logic in your output - especially as it contains values that are not in the input.

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <businessElements>
        <key>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        </key>
        <type>???</type>
        <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </value>
    </businessElements>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This takes all the leaf nodes (elements that do not have other elements as their children) and transform them to  a `businessElements` node, where `key` is the name of the original element and `value` is its string-value.

I am not sure where the `type` value should come from.

Applied to the following **well-formed (!)** input example:

**XML**

```
<entity1>
   <requestID>TV00001001</requestID>
    <entity2>
      <effectiveDt>2001-12-31T12:00:00</effectiveDt>
      <companyCd>companyCd</companyCd>
      <entity3>
         <vo1>
            <att1>true</att1>
            <att2>vehicleId</att2>
            <att3>true</att3>
         </vo1>
      </entity3>
   </entity2>
</entity1>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity1>
   <businessElements>
      <key>requestID</key>
      <type>???</type>
      <value>TV00001001</value>
   </businessElements>
   <entity2>
      <businessElements>
         <key>effectiveDt</key>
         <type>???</type>
         <value>2001-12-31T12:00:00</value>
      </businessElements>
      <businessElements>
         <key>companyCd</key>
         <type>???</type>
         <value>companyCd</value>
      </businessElements>
      <entity3>
         <vo1>
            <businessElements>
               <key>att1</key>
               <type>???</type>
               <value>true</value>
            </businessElements>
            <businessElements>
               <key>att2</key>
               <type>???</type>
               <value>vehicleId</value>
            </businessElements>
            <businessElements>
               <key>att3</key>
               <type>???</type>
               <value>true</value>
            </businessElements>
         </vo1>
      </entity3>
   </entity2>
</entity1>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. For the Type , is it possible to import an xsd and match on the element name and get type .

Comment: XSLT is completely new to me and bit overwhelming on the generic approach , I am trying to take . I was not sure , if it was even possible

Comment: "*is it possible to import an xsd and match on the element name and get type*"  Possibly. I suggest you ask about that in a new question - after you have everything else running satisfactorily.